# Mockito marks mocks as verified even though they are not

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I use Mockito.verifiyNoMoreInteractions(mock1, mock2, ...) at the end of my JUnit5 Tests. I recently realized that it doesn't show mocks at the end that haven't been verified yet, because i simply forgot to call verify().

I debugged the code and used Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations() to show me all invocations on that mock. To my surprise whenever a method was called on the mock, a invocation got added to the list, but with the field "verified" set to true, which in turn makes it not show up when calling verifyNoMoreInteractions().

I expect that all invocations have to be verified by an explicit verify() call.

Am I understanding something wrong here or is the issue on Mockito's side?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Testclass im using (test runs green even tho it should not):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserManagerTest {

    UserManager userManager;

    @Mock
    DataNetworkPlugin dataNetworkPlugin;

    @Mock
    Source source;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        initializeTest();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(source, dataNetworkPlugin);
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    private void initializeTest() {         
        when(dataNetworkPlugin.getElement(anyString())).thenReturn(source);
        when(source.asDataSource()).thenReturn(null);

        userManager = UserManager.createInstance(dataNetworkPlugin);
    }
}
```

dataNetworkPlugin.getElement("") and source.asDataSource() are both called inside UserManager.createInstance().

UPDATE 2:

If i change my tearDown method to the following it still works. Mockito is not telling me that i am verifying too much.

```
@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
    verify(source).asDataSource();
    verify(dataNetworkPlugin).getElement();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(source, dataNetworkPlugin);
}
```

Comment: can you update the question and share a runnable example?

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon the same issue, but it actually seems like expected behaviour in JUnit5.

Statement is based on referencing this quote:

> [...] You just need to keep in mind that the method calls that you have explicitly stubbed are verified automatically. You might typically need to verify interactions that have no side effects, e.g. void methods. In the end it's less code but a similar end result - just confusing to begin with when migrating from junit 4.

Source: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1610#issuecomment-758975695